# Forcing a type of syntax highlighting in geany with an in-source comment?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, geany

I often use assembly for various CPUs using geany as the editor. My problem that I can't assign syntax highlight schemes quite well according to file name extensions like .asm, as I would need other scheme in two different files having the very same .asm in the file name (but they are asm source for different CPU and assembler). Also, I have other files, like "*.inc" I would like to use with a given assembly syntax.

My idea: is it possible somehow to force a given highlight syntax by a comment in the file itself (overriding the syntax by the file extension decision completely)? It would be the best solution though I am not sure if geany can do this.

Though I am not a great expert in vim, as far as I know vim also supports some kind of statements for the editor itself defined by simple comment inside the file. I'd like a solution like this with geany on the syntax highlighting. I don't like the solution to switch syntax highlight type through menus too much ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is the route:

```
Document -> Set Filetype -> Programming Languages -> Assembler
```

Comment: That's OK, I've also found it, but my problem that I don't want to set the file type manually each time, also I have the same filename extension with different types. That's why I thought there can be a way to insert a comment in the file itself to control the behaviour of the editor, since it works in case of some editors (as far as I know, vim for example)

Comment: Note that if you close geany (without closing all your tabs) when you'll fire up geany again the custom syntax highlighting will be kept. So, this answer works for me :)